# Newbie IOS Class Method

Tags: objective-c, ios, cs193p

On assignment 2 of the Stanford CS193P course it states that I must add a runProgram class method with the following signature:

```
+ (double)runProgram:(id)program
usingVariableValues:(NSDictionary *)variableValues;
```

However I do not recognise or know how to use this syntax as up until now methods have been written more simply:

```
+ (double)performOperation:(NSString *)operation
```

Could someone explain this signature?
Should the method be written on one line?
How do I get/set my dictionary?

Sorry for the basic questions but I am a complete beginner!

Answer (score 1):

```
+ (double)runProgram:(id)program
 usingVariableValues:(NSDictionary *)variableValues;
```

Is the same as:

```
+ (double)runProgram:(id)program usingVariableValues:(NSDictionary *)variableValues;
```

It is formatted on two lines for easier reading.

In this declaration, your selector is: `runProgram:usingVariableValues:`, and after colons are argument names with their types, i.e. `program` of type `id` and `variableValues` of type `NSDictionary *`.

You call it using

```
[ClassName runProgram:myProgram usingVariableValues:myVariables];
```

To create a dictionary, you use code like this:

```
NSDictionary *myDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value1",
                        @"key1", @"value2", @"key2", nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be on one line for readability:

```
+ (double)runProgram:(id)program usingVariableValues:(NSDictionary *)variableValues;
```

Usage is just as you would expect:

```
[MyCustomClass runProgram:myProgram usingVariableValues:myDictionary];
```

Answer (score 0):

Class method are not any new method, basic differences here -
1. In Signature of Method
2. Accessible by ClassName instead of Class Object

```
+ (double)runProgram:(id)program usingVariableValues:(NSDictionary *)variableValues;
```

is same as -

```
+ (double)runProgram:(id)program
 usingVariableValues:(NSDictionary *)variableValues;
```

While calling this method -

```
[ClassName runProgram:someProgram usingVariableValues:someVar];
```

or in formatted way -

```
[ClassName runProgram:someProgram 
  usingVariableValues:someVar];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (double)runProgram:(id)program usingVariableValues:(NSDictionary *)variableValues;
```

is simply a method taking two parameters, one of type id and one a dictionary.  In Objective-C, parameters are interleaved into the selector.  So to invoke this method you would do

```
[MyClass runProgram: aProgram usingVariableValues: aDictionary];
```

aDictionary is a dictionary you need to construct before invoking the method.  The easiest way is to do this is to create a mutable dictionary and add the items one by one.

```
NSMutableDictionary* aDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[aDictionary setObject: @"foo" forKey: @"bar"];
[aDictionary setObject: @"baz" forKey: @"fizz"];
// etc
```